# Can I create a Calligraphy look with SVG?

Tags: svg

is it possible to create a stroke with a dynamic width with SVG? I want to achieve a Calligraphy look like [here](http://inkscape.org/doc/calligraphy/tutorial-calligraphy.html), [here](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/PowerStroke) or [here](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-illustrator-cc/creating-a-calligraphic-brush-in-illustrator-cc/).

Is this even possible? It seems customization of strokes in SVG is fairly limited. Even gradients in strokes seem to be non-trivial (see [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4163057)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a proposal to add into SVG standard a mechanism, that does exactly what you want:

- http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/Variable_width_stroke
- http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2013May/0041.html

There's even an example implementation available here:

- https://rawgit.com/birtles/curvy/master/index.html

It is, however, by no means official and we cannot be even sure it'll ever be.

---

Until then you'll need to stick to Bezier curves and object filling:
[image: Bezier curves]

---

You can also use calligraphic fonts, for example - Tangerine available on [Google CDN](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Tangerine):

[image: Tangerine]

This approach requires less work since you don't need to draw everything from scratch, but then again, using third party fonts leaves you with little control over the final result.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links and explanation. Just in case you know it: can I respond to this topic in some GitHub repo? (Sometimes it seems the specs also use GitHub issues as a feedback channel besides the mailing list.)

Comment: Some people accept issues as a way of communication with developers, but some don't. I think it's better to contact someone via e-mail first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically adjust the stroke of a path element.  However you could draw a path, use a fill color on it instead of stroke, then double back upon the letters at a slight distance away from the original line.

Also, if you are using the SVG on the web then you can use css fonts on text elements.  There are some pretty good cursive fonts that you can use for free... just check google web fonts.